# SSIS Package Does Not Run Excel 365

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm creating an SSIS Package which imports data from an Excel file located in Onedrive and stores that data in SQL table. This package perfectly executes in Visual Studio. But when the package is deployed to SQL, the execution fails and I get this error

[image]

Visual Studio - 2015
SQL Server - Windows Server 2019 Standard (10.0)
SSMS - 18

Steps I have tried:

1. Installed Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 on my local machine
2. Set deployment properties to 32 bit

Please help!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you "Installed Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 on" the _server_? When you run the package, are you specifying that it needs to use the 32 bit executable (deployment properties won't affect run)

Comment: *"Installed Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 on my local machine"* It's no good on your local machine if SQL Server is running on a different host, which it presumably is.